# How to create multiple child records based on the value provided on parent entity in d365 CRM

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, plugins, dynamics-crm

I have two entities called detail (Parent) and spot (child). In the parent entity I have a "whole number" field called "quantity". In the child entity I have a "lookup" field "detail(parent)". If quantity has number 5 then, I need to create a 5 spot record (based on "quantity" value I need to create number spot records) and need to assign corresponding parent lookup.

I just don't understand how to start with this. I'm new to CRM and plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `spot` records need to be created upon creation of a `detail` record, a plugin can be registered on the post create step of detail.

The plugin could look similar like this:

```cs
public class DetailPlugin: IPlugin
{
    public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
        Entity detailEntity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
        int quantity = detailEntity.GetAttributeValue<int>("new_quantity");

        if (quantity <= 0)
            return;

        Guid detailId = (Guid)context.OutputParameters["id"];
        var serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
        IOrganizationService organizationService = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.InitiatingUserId);

        for (int x = 0; x < quantity; x++)
        {
            organizationService.Create(new Entity("new_spot")
            {
                ["new_detailid"] = new EntityReference("new_detail", detailId)
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great, I'd also suggest if there is a need to create children with their parents, use AddRelatedObject Method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/gg307129(v%3Dcrm.8)  This makes it all one transaction.  If there are plugins / workflows that fire on create of the child, that need to access the a parent, you'll see errors, as the parent won't exist when the child is created, but overall this will be grouped into one transaction.

Comment: Thanks, upvote the answer? Regarding your suggestion, I doubt if it adds any value. In a synchronous post create stage all work is already done within a database transaction, so I do not expect issues with other plugins or workflows here. Plugin triggers only fire after the commit. Also I would not recommend using the `OrganizationServiceContext` in plugins. It maintains state where it is not needed and I feel it adds complexity. When not handled carefully it also tends to introduce unexpected (erroneous) behaviour.

Comment: Regarding my statement "Plugin triggers only fire after the commit.": this is only true for async plugins. Synchronous plugins that trigger within in the scope of the database transaction have access to the data that are created/modified within that transaction.